# How to properly implement drag and drop for text with Gtk in Mono-C#?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, mono, gtk

I'd like to implement an application where users can add text to it using drag and drop. Somehow I can find no sufficient example on the web helping me in this task. There are plenty of examples for Windows, but I am planning to implement this using Gtk and Mono on Linux.

I created a widget - a label in my case - and added the following code to the main window:

```
Gtk.Drag.DestSet (label1, DestDefaults.Drop, new TargetEntry[] {
    new TargetEntry("text/plain", TargetFlags.Widget, 0)
}, Gdk.DragAction.Copy);
label1.DragMotion += new Gtk.DragMotionHandler(OnLabelDragMotion);
```

The method OnLabelDragMotion() gets called if a drag something onto the control. This part works fine. But now how do I start from here? How do I recognize if the user actually dropped something onto the control?

Comment: You may have to use a [`GdkDragContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Drag-and-Drop.html). I've never used it, so I don't know. They say you shouldn't have to use that, though. It is very cryptic how you do it.

Comment: I found several fragments of examples and tutorials which lead in that direction I go, but unfortunately none of them addressing drag and drop of text and regular controls. Nevertheless if this is 'cryptic' - how do you implement it less 'cryptic'? I am very eager to learn how to implement proper drag and drop on Mono in Linux! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the way: As you can see I am not yet doing anything :-( I could NOT figure out how to implement drag and drop properly. I get notifications that there is someone dragging something (for debugging purposes). That's it. Everything else did not work because I simply don't know how to do this properly. And I can't seem to find any useful information on the web. Therefor I am seeking for help here: What do I have to do to actually accept drag and drop attempts?

Comment: See the manual and try the example http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-DragAndDrop.html

Comment: Thanks, but the python documentation is inexact in some aspects. And I would require a documentation of the Gtk-Mono data structures: The class structure is different. Therefor I can't find all necessary C# equivalents to python methods.. Is there a documentation somewhere on the web targeting C#? Doesn't look like that :-(

Comment: Please be patient: I will continue on this question at the end of next week. Well, maybe I've found the answer myself. Without any suitable documentation :-/